# xpages Value picker multiple databaseNames

Tags: xpages

Is it possible inside a `<xe:valuePicker>` to declare 2 daatabaseNames ?

I want to concatenate 2 views from 2 different databases and letting the user having the right to select more than one value.

For the first view, I do want all the entries listed.

For the 2nd view,  I'd want to grab the entries like:

```
@Unique(@DbLookup("server!!my.nsf", "vwNumeCP", hehe, 2));
```

where

```
var hehe = docProiect.getItemValueString("Comp");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could  use a `beanValuePicker` data provider, and pull in the data from the two different databases in your managed bean, if you are comfortable working in java. Create a Java class that implements `IValuePickerData`. See [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+XPages+Extension+Library#action=openDocument&res_title=Value_and_name_pickers_ddxl853&content=pdcontent) and [here](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=listpicker-dataprovider-for-value-picker) for info on creating a managed bean data provider.

Or you may be able to use a `simpleValuePicker` data provider, and in the `valueList` property use SSJS to pull the data in from your two sources.

Otherwise as a work-around/hack-around, the `namePicker` control has a data provider available to it called `namePickerAggregator` that allows you to define multiple data providers to be shown in the picker, including using data from different databases. But there's no such provider for a valuePicker. If you were willing to accept the slightly different UI that comes with a name picker versus a value picker, then use the namePickerAggregator with two dominoViewValuePicker data providers. Something like this:

```
<xe:namePicker id="myPicker" for="inputText1">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:namePickerAggregator>
            <xe:this.dataProviders>
                <xe:dominoViewNamePicker databaseName="database1.nsf" viewName="AllNames" labelColumn="Name" label="Database1"></xe:dominoViewNamePicker>
                <xe:dominoViewNamePicker databaseName="database2.nsf" viewName="AllNames" labelColumn="Name" label="Database2"></xe:dominoViewNamePicker>
            </xe:this.dataProviders>
        </xe:namePickerAggregator>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

Comment: I need to access the view, considering a component value, such as this: @Unique(@DbLookup("server!!my.nsf", "vwNumeCP", companie, 2));, where companie is a field value. If I just write the view name, I get all the entries.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the beanValuePicker are the mapPicker and listPicker classes that I've added XSnippets for http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=mappicker-dataprovider-for-vaue-picker. This allows you to pass a Java List, Set or Map in as the source. I've also done a series of blog posts about it http://www.intec.co.uk/tag/selections-tutorial/

The Java classes have been incorporated into OpenNTF Domino API as native dataProviders.

Comment: These classes have been incorporated into core ExtLib for some years. Don't use the Snippets, they've already been marked deprecated.